# Rate of evaporation/mass loss of liquid in a bowl

Tags: thermodynamics, evaporation, gas, liquid-state

Say a hemispherical bowl filled with a liquid was left in a room. I was wondering how we could model the rate of mass loss of liquid as it evaporates.

What factors will it specifically depend on? (because of the bowl shape, the surface area would decrease as the liquid evaporates)

Assuming that the rate of change of volume is proportional to the exposed surface area:

$$\frac{dV}{dt} = -kA$$

$$\frac{d(\frac{1}{2}\pi r^3)}{dt} = -k\pi r^2$$

... $$r = - \frac{2}{3}kt + c$$

where $c$ is the radius of the liquid in the bowl at $t=0$

The rate of change of volume could be calculated:

$$V = \frac{1}{2}\pi r^3$$

$$\frac{dV}{dt} =\frac{3}{2}\pi r^2 \frac{dr}{dt} = \frac{3}{2}\pi(- \frac{2}{3}kt + c)^2(-\frac{2}{3}k)$$

$$\frac{dV}{dt} = -\frac{4k^3 \pi}{9}t^2 + \frac{4k^2 \pi c}{3}t - k \pi c^2$$

and so we could find the rate of mass loss by:

$$\frac{dm}{dt} = \rho \frac{dV}{dt} $$

Would like to know what the constant $k $ depends on. Is it something to do with the room conditions, or maybe something like the diffusivity of the vapour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a combination of thermodyynamics, fluid dynamics and heat transfer (so you will need much more equations).

On the water surface, knowing the temperature, we can estimate the vapor pressure and vapor mixture fraction. Then there will be an diffusion process for the water vapor to move out and for the ambient air to move in. Because the water surface doesn't allow the air to further move, a circulation forms. When the water vapor moves out, the water vapor pressure drops, so more liquid water evaporates to fill up the loss of water vapor. The evaporation associates latent heat so water surface area temperature drops (you may see dew on the bowl wall). Then a heat transfer process starts which may initiate water circulation as well.

As this is complex, doing test might be a quick way to get the K value if you assume it is a constant, which is questionable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe taking a look at Hertz–Knudsen theory could help you. Because it's a thermodynamic problem, and tou need to take the pressure balance into account between the atmosphere, and the water vapor just beetween the water and the air.